# Upper bound on the number of permutations which have $r$-th roots

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Given $\mathfrak S_n$, I am trying to find the number of distinct permutations $y$ such that a permutation $x$ exists with  $x^r = y$. Here power means composition.

The paper https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82287751.pdf  gives an estimate for $r=2$. I am trying to calculate such bounds for $r=3$ and $6$.

Kindly provide some references on how to proceed.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A103619